# I can't see my objects in Solid mode, but I can see them in Rendered Mode

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh

My object disappear in Solid Mode but when I turn to Rendered Mode they appear back but cannot select them.

[image: Solid Mode]
[image: Render Mode]

Comment: Link to Project : http://www.mediafire.com/file/7p5tv60hcj8k4sp/isometric_roomn.blend

Comment: You hide it in the outliner. Click on the little greyed eye in the outliner near the outside light.

Comment: @FFeller: unhide didnt solve it, this window object is completely invisible in any mode and I checked all the filtering options ...

Comment: I solved it!
I made a new Layout. I removed the old bug Layout.

Answer (score 1):

When I open your file its not visible even in Render Mode.
Really strange behaviour.

But if you are looking for solution - **turn off and on your "OBJECT" collection** (check mark on left side of Outliner editor).

[image]

Note: Do the same for "MAIN" collection, there are also hidden objects that should not be (like ceiling and totaly discoverable window object). Is not the blend file from some older blender version?

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, consider hit a check mark next to an answer as solved (green), so others can see it from main Q list too. Thank you

Comment: I did the same thing you said and now they are all gone. but still remain visible in Rendered Mode.

Comment: This is created in Blender 2.8 which is the version i'm using rightnow

Comment: Download current official 2.81a version (there are some viewport fixies, it might help) Aslo try to check Outliner > Filter and click on other icons than eye to see if there is not something disabled on a object list.

Comment: ok will do, thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and still didn't figure it out. But when I go to the top panel "Modeling" I can see it normally. Doesn't solve the problem but atleast goes around it! :D [image: cannot see anything][image: modeling tab]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the layout workspace and create another workspace, that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi, Cal Ro. At first sight this looks like a workaround to bug.. you could improve this answer for others by including your version and OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but turning off and on the collection didn't work for me.

I'd noticed that all my invisible objects were with modifiers, so, I just hide all visible objects, try to select invisible ones and apply all modifiers and it works for me.

Also if you don't want to apply all modifiers, you can add random temporary object to the scene, add the same modifiers of invisible object, select them both and join.

Then you can separate them using <kbd>P</kbd> in *Edit Mode* or delete the temporary object's vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found easier way to solve this problem. Go to Edit - Preferences - Viewport - Subdivision - uncheck GPU Subdivision. I guess the problem is in weak GPU.